# Save the state of a table view/ save the state of the table view text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView and i can add and delete cells. I also have two buttons on each cell to add and subtract 1 from the cells text. But when i go to a different page and then back to the table view page, all the cells text is set back to `1`. But i want the cell's text to stay at the value that the user had set it to! Could someone help me? Im not sure what to do whatsoever. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to maintain an `NSMutableArray` (probably of `NSIntegers`) that saves the values of the cells. Then, whenever the user changes the value, update the value in the array. Also, display the cell label values by reading from the array. Sample codes below-

```
-(void)plusButtonClicked:(id)sender
{ 
    //figure out the cell index which was updated using sender
    //update the array entry
    //[self.array objectAtIndex:index]++; self.array is the array you will maintain
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    cell.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```

If you want the values to persist even after the app is terminated and restarted, consider using CoreData.

Comment: do you know of a good tutorial for how to save a table view's state using core data? I have searched and i was unable to find anything helpful! Thanks for the help!